# Store and display the date of registration of a user

Tags: php, mysql, database, date, registration

I am making a registration form with 8-10 fields. Apart from this I have 2 other fields in my database, userid which is a primary key wioth auto incrementation and an active field, whether the user is active or not. But I want to add one more field, that is the registration date and store it in IST (Indian Standard Time)

When I click my profile link in stackoverflow, I see that I have registered X months back and I have visited the site X number of times. I want to add a similar feature to the profile of my users which displays the exact date and time when they were registered! Ex, member since: 28/7/2001! Something like that.

Do I have to do any tweak in my registration form? Or do I have to do any other thing? I searched on google and stackoverflow for the same, searched the php and mysql documentation too, saw a lot of things about dates and timestamps but I don't know how to go about, didn't get exactly what I wanted and wasn't convinced enough. Please help me solve this problem.

Thank you!

Comment: just get the date on registration and store it in mysql with `datetime` datatype that's it, And just get the current date on login time and calculate it and display according to your need.

Comment: tell us wat u have tried so far, then fellas around here will try to help.

Comment: I have successfully stored the date and time in DB as you guys have helped. I am not facing trouble on how to show when the last time the user has logged in.

Comment: However, I will try more things about the last time log in thing and come back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to tweak your form.

Just add field "registration_date" to your "user" table.

Set it to the current date when inserting a new user.

This can be done at the database level.

Something like this:

```
INSERT INTO `user` ( `registration_date`, other fields...) 
VALUES (NOW(), other values...);
```

Your form doesn't need to pass "registration_date" to the database.

Be aware that NOW() function returns the database server datetime.

Comment: it would be great if your choose the correct datatype for your filed like `registration_date` field has the `datetime` datatype.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Worked like a charm. Just that I was passing the fields as arrays and I passed the NOW() within quotes :| Rectified it though :)

Answer (score 0):

Store in database using `NOW()`

or generate date with PHP

```
$date=(Y-m-d);
```